# Primary key index is not used in join

Tags: sql, mysql

TL;DR query is making a full table scan on a simple join statement and I don't know why, see the last `EXPLAIN` output for details

---

I have a use case where I have to find a value closest to 12:00 for each day in range. I found a way to generate a list of days in another Stack Overflow question:

```sql
with recursive
    dates (date) as
        (select cast('2022-01-01' as date)
         union all
         select date + interval 1 day
         from dates
         where date < '2023-01-01')
```

Then I call my function that returns an ID of a row that I want then to return to my back-end:

```sql
    ids as (select closest_to_noon(date(date), 2) as id
           from dates)
```

The entire query looks like:

```sql
with recursive
    dates (date) as
        (select cast('2022-01-01' as date)
         union all
         select date + interval 1 day
         from dates
         where date < '2023-01-01'),
    ids as (select closest_to_noon(date(date), 2) as id
           from dates)
select * from ids
```

It executes in ~170 ms for a whole year, here's an explain:

```
+--+-----------+----------+----------+----+-------------+----+-------+----+----+--------+----------------------+
|id|select_type|table     |partitions|type|possible_keys|key |key_len|ref |rows|filtered|Extra                 |
+--+-----------+----------+----------+----+-------------+----+-------+----+----+--------+----------------------+
|1 |PRIMARY    |<derived3>|null      |ALL |null         |null|null   |null|3   |100     |null                  |
|3 |DERIVED    |null      |null      |null|null         |null|null   |null|null|null    |No tables used        |
|4 |UNION      |dates     |null      |ALL |null         |null|null   |null|2   |50      |Recursive; Using where|
+--+-----------+----------+----------+----+-------------+----+-------+----+----+--------+----------------------+
```

Now, I can join the target table with my list of IDs:

```sql
# `with` ommited for brevity
select *
from ids
         join weather_condition w on w.id = ids.id;
```

The time increased by a whopping 1.6s just by using a simple join (1.77s in total). I'm pretty sure it's because a full table scan is done, but I don't know how to make it use an index:

```
+--+-----------+----------+----------+----+-------------+----+-------+----+-------+--------+------------------------------------------+
|id|select_type|table     |partitions|type|possible_keys|key |key_len|ref |rows   |filtered|Extra                                     |
+--+-----------+----------+----------+----+-------------+----+-------+----+-------+--------+------------------------------------------+
|1 |PRIMARY    |<derived3>|null      |ALL |null         |null|null   |null|3      |100     |null                                      |
|1 |PRIMARY    |w         |null      |ALL |null         |null|null   |null|5427992|10      |Using where; Using join buffer (hash join)|
|3 |DERIVED    |null      |null      |null|null         |null|null   |null|null   |null    |No tables used                            |
|4 |UNION      |dates     |null      |ALL |null         |null|null   |null|2      |50      |Recursive; Using where                    |
+--+-----------+----------+----------+----+-------------+----+-------+----+-------+--------+------------------------------------------+
```

*(renamed/omitted fields for brevity)*

```
+---------------+---------+----+---+-------+--------------+
|Field          |Type     |Null|Key|Default|Extra         |
+---------------+---------+----+---+-------+--------------+
|id             |bigint   |NO  |PRI|null   |auto_increment|
|XXXX           |timestamp|NO  |   |null   |              |
|XXXX           |int      |NO  |MUL|null   |              |
|XXXX           |bigint   |NO  |MUL|null   |              |
|XXXX           |int      |NO  |MUL|null   |              |
+---------------+---------+----+---+-------+--------------+
```

How do I make the query use an index?

---

I've tried changing `max_seeks_for_key` as indicated by another Stack Overflow post, but it does not have an effect. It is still taking the same amount of time with force index (which does not work by the way).

```sql
# `with` ommited for brevity
select *
from ids
         join weather_condition w force index (`PRIMARY`) on w.id = ids.id;
```

```
+--+-----------+----------+----------+----+-------------+----+-------+----+-------+--------+------------------------------------------+
|id|select_type|table     |partitions|type|possible_keys|key |key_len|ref |rows   |filtered|Extra                                     |
+--+-----------+----------+----------+----+-------------+----+-------+----+-------+--------+------------------------------------------+
|1 |PRIMARY    |<derived3>|null      |ALL |null         |null|null   |null|3      |100     |null                                      |
|1 |PRIMARY    |w         |null      |ALL |null         |null|null   |null|5427992|10      |Using where; Using join buffer (hash join)|
|3 |DERIVED    |null      |null      |null|null         |null|null   |null|null   |null    |No tables used                            |
|4 |UNION      |dates     |null      |ALL |null         |null|null   |null|2      |50      |Recursive; Using where                    |
+--+-----------+----------+----------+----+-------------+----+-------+----+-------+--------+------------------------------------------+
```

I'm using MySQL 8.0.35.

Comment: Have you tried adding use index or force index hints to the query?

Comment: ah yes tried that one as well, didn't work

Comment: Then mysql doea not think that the primary key would help in that join.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it would help, since if I get the IDs and do `select * from weather_condition where id in (<IDs here>)` then it takes like 15ms instead of 1500ms

Comment: also another question suggested that changing `max_seeks_for_key` would help in such case (where the db does not think it would help) but it had no effect

Comment: I see you voted to reopen the question. I think that's the wrong action as this question is the exact duplicate of the other one. You probably asked the wrong question. Using the in clause results in a different resultset as with the join and select * you are returning all columns from both tables. With the in clause you return columns from one table only and you list of ids may be a lot shorter than what  the CTE returns. Comparing apples with pears is not a great benchmark.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256196/discussion-between-eeqk-and-shadow).

Comment: I've migrated the database to postgres and query there takes 55ms instead of ~1800ms in mysql. I'll just switch to postgres moving forward. I'm not sure if that's the case but it'd make sense if mysql was just not smart enough to use index in this scenario